# Как рисовать линии svg при прокрутке колесиком мышки?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation

Есть svg, нужно отображать его рисуя линии (его кривые) в зависимости от прокручивания колесика. То есть крутишь колесико, рисуются линии. Когда один свг нарисовался, нужно чтобы он медленно исчез и появился другой. На нем тоже нужно отрисовать одну линии крутя колесико. и тд. Так 25 слайдов.

Подскажите куда глядеть, и что для этого лучше всего подойдет?

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html

Comment: @KuatMustafin было бы здорово, если вы объяснили в ответе всю механику этого эффекта, чтобы не нужно было переходить по ссылкам и разбираться в исходном коде – так ответ будет супер-полезен многим другим читателям.

Comment: @KuatMustafin Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сначала измеряется длина пути патча с помощью команды `getTotalLength`

Ниже пример измерения длины линии зеленого чекбокса.

```html
<title> Измерение длины пути</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
   
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="100%" height="100%" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="green" stroke-width ="1" 
         d="M 34.6 14.6  L 21 28.2 L 15.4 22.6 L 12.6 25.4 L 21 33.8 L 37.4 17.4z" /> 
</svg> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

Далее полученная цифра подставляется в `stroke-dasharray` и  `stroke-dashoffset` при этом получается, что длина пробела становится равной длине линии. Затем начинается плавное уменьшение `stroke-dashoffset`. Таким образом достигается эффект анимации рисования линии с чистого листа. У `stroke-dasharray` два атрибута. Первый задает длину штриха, второй - пробел, но если они равны, можно ставить только одну цифру.
В примере ниже я сделал двойной эффект - сначала исчезновение контура, затем его рисование с чистого листа. Для стирания контура `stroke-dashoffset` ставится в минимальное значение, затем следует плавное увеличение до максимума. 
Другими словами, если `stroke-dashoffset` стремится к нулю, то происходит рисование линии.
Если `stroke-dashoffset` увеличивается, то идет процесс стирания линии.
[Практика и теория здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1253#more-1253)

```html
<svg  id="Rein" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="228" height="366" viewBox="274.99 129 114 183" >
<title>animation Reindeer</title> 
  
 <g>
      <path  stroke-width="0.8" stroke="saddlebrown" stroke-dasharray="953" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m344 129c-2 0-5 3-6 4-5 6-2 10 2 15 4 5 8 8 12 12-1 0-2 1-3 2-5-6-10-5-15-3 4 4 4 9 14 11l3 20c2 11 1 10-5 13-7 3-18 4-31 1-8-4-17-5-24-2l0 0c-3-2-5-6-6-11-3 5-5 9 0 15-1 6-4 12-3 18 2 15 6 16 4 18-3 4-5 8-9 11l1 47-2 5c3 2 7 3 10 2l-2-6-1-17 3-23c4-7 4-8 8-14l3 14c9 13 16 27 22 42l-1 7c3 2 7 2 10 0-6-16-10-32-20-48 6-5 11-12 13-21 13 5 18 2 28 1-1 8-3 15-2 23l-6 15 3 22-4 6c2 2 7 5 10 2l0-27c15-5 26-10 34-22 4-3 6-7 3-12-7-6-12-12-16-17 8-16 8-22 1-36l-4-11c7-1 9-2 15-5 9-3 6-7 4-10-7 0-14 2-17-3-3-4-5-9-12-8l-3-3c5-4 7-5 9-10 1-4-1-6-3-8-6-8-7-1-6 1l2 5c3 5-3 8-7 10-3-3-6-6-8-9-4-5 4-8 3-12 0-1-1-1-2-1m366 242c-3 8-8 20-12 32 8-4 12-6 19-13 5-5 6-8 0-13z" fill="none">
         <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="Rein.click" values="0; 953; 0" dur="20s" repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>
     
   </path>
  <path  stroke-width="1"  d="m366 242c-3 8-8 20-12 32 8-4 12-6 19-13 5-5 6-8 0-13z" fill="#DDDDDD"/>  
  </g>
         <text  x="320" y="190" font-size="10" font-family="Ariel" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="none" stroke="saddlebrown" stroke-width="0.5px" >Click me</text>
</svg>
```

Ещё пример

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 
 width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
   <title>animation logo picasa</title> 
    
  
    <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke ="black" stroke-dasharray= "600" stroke-dashoffset="0"  d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.1 30.8c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 46 81.7 30.8 63.1 30.8zM63.1 40.1c3.5 0 6.9 0.8 10.2 2.2 0 0.3 0 15.3 0 16.4 -0.8-0.8-18.1-16.4-18.8-17C57.3 40.6 60.1 40.1 63.1 40.1zM38.5 64.7c0-9.3 5.1-17.7 13.4-21.9 0.3 0.3 8.9 8.1 9.3 8.5 -0.4 0.4-21.2 19.2-21.8 19.8C38.8 69 38.5 66.8 38.5 64.7zM50.4 85.7c-4.6-2.8-8.2-7-10.2-11.9 0.3-0.3 9.4-8.5 10.2-9.2C50.4 65.7 50.4 84.8 50.4 85.7zM65.3 89.2h-4.5c-2.7-0.2-5.3-0.9-7.8-2.1 0-0.4 0-11.2 0-11.7 0.5 0 31.3 0 32.2 0C81.4 83.2 73.8 88.4 65.3 89.2zM86.3 72.8c-0.4 0-10 0-10.5 0 0-0.5 0-28.1 0-29.1 7.3 4.5 11.9 12.4 11.9 21C87.7 67.4 87.2 70.2 86.3 72.8z" >
 <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" values="600; 0" dur="10s" repeatCount="1"  fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear"/>
 </path>
    <text  x="98" y="17" font-size="11" font-family="Ariel" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="green" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5px" >Click me</text>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Эффект "рисования" достигается при помощи установки нужного значения атрибута stroke-dasharray и плавного изменения атрибута stroke-dashoffset SVG-фигур.

Атрибут stroke-dasharray меняет контуры на штриховые линии вместо сплошных.
stroke-dashoffset определяет смещение начала первого штриха в штриховом паттерне.

```js
var radio = true;

function play() {
  var path = document.getElementById('path');
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = (radio) ? '0' : '988.00';
  radio = !radio;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="98" width="581" viewBox="0 0 581 98">
    <path id="path" d="M62.9 14.9c-25-7.74-56.6 4.8-60.4 24.3-3.73 19.6 21.6 35 39.6 37.6 42.8 6.2 72.9-53.4 116-58.9 65-18.2 191 101 215 28.8 5-16.7-7-49.1-34-44-34 11.5-31 46.5-14 69.3 9.38 12.6 24.2 20.6 39.8 22.9 91.4 9.05 102-98.9 176-86.7 18.8 3.81 33 17.3 36.7 34.6 2.01 10.2.124 21.1-5.18 30.1"
    stroke="#000" stroke-width="4.3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="988.00 988.00" style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out; stroke-dashoffset: 988.00;"></path>
  </svg>
  <button onclick="play();">Play</button>
</body>
```